# WPF dynamically set context for a TabItem ContentTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a TabControl that should display different values on a common template and I made something like this that properly works:

```
      <TabControl>
            <TabItem Header="Infos" DataContext="{Binding InfoHistory}" >
                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}" Header="Time"/>
                            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message}" Header="Message"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
            </TabItem>
            <TabItem Header="Warnings" DataContext="{Binding WarningHistory}"  />
            <TabItem Header="Errors" DataContext="{Binding ErrorHistory}"  />
        </TabControl>
```

Since the template is the same for the three TabItem I was trying to move the TabItemContent in a DataTemplate like this:

```
        <TabControl>
            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabItem}}}">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}" Header="Time"/>
                                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message}" Header="Message"/>
                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <TabItem Header="Infos" DataContext="{Binding InfoHistory}" />
            <TabItem Header="Warnings" DataContext="{Binding WarningHistory}"  />
            <TabItem Header="Errors" DataContext="{Binding ErrorHistory}"  />
        </TabControl>
```

However this version does not work. It shows an empty ListView, much like it cant find the DataContext. 
Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ContentTemplates get their DataContext set to their Content, rather than their content's DataContext, so bind your TabItem Content properties instead:

```
<TabItem Header="Infos" Content="{Binding InfoHistory}" />
<TabItem Header="Warnings" Content="{Binding WarningHistory}"  />
<TabItem Header="Errors" Content="{Binding ErrorHistory}"  />
```

And then simply bind your ListBox to its own DataContext:

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            ... etc ...
        </ListView>
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Comment: this answer helped me to fix lost binding when switching from auto-created TabItems (based on `ItemsSource`) to explicit TabItems: `<Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding}"/>` under `<TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>` solves the issue :)